# Create an object / model out of JSON data, that is not an exact copy of the wanted model-object

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization, google-ads-api

How would one in an OOP-way "hydrate", "map", "create" (or whatever it's called) an object or model representation of this JSON data. The JSON string I've included below is the raw data received from Google's AdWords API and is not an exact copy of the structure I want and need, and I may therefor not just cast it to an object and similar.

I've been looking at various mapping libraries and hydration libraries but I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to get it to work properly.

```
{
  "report-name": {
    "@name": "Criteria performance report #5b3e67189ac85",
  },
  "date-range": {
    "@date": "Jun 5, 2018-Jul 4, 2018",
  },
  "table": {
    "columns": {
      "column": [
        {
          "@name": "adGroup",
          "@display": "Ad group",
        },
        {
          "@name": "impressions",
          "@display": "Impressions",
        },
        {
          "@name": "clicks",
          "@display": "Clicks",
        },
        {
          "@name": "cost",
          "@display": "Cost",
        }
      ]
    },
    "row": [
      {
        "@adGroup": "Ad Group 1 of Another Campaign",
        "@impressions": 0,
        "@clicks": 0,
        "@cost": 0,
      },
      {
        "@adGroup": "Ad group 1 of Initial Campaign",
        "@impressions": 0,
        "@clicks": 0,
        "@cost": 0,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would imagine the object or model looking kind of like this.
There are different types of reports, but the structure look exactly the same, just the items are not containing the same attributes. The posted JSON structure represents an "AdGroup", meaning the "rows" would need to get de-serialized into different models. Basically calling "getRowItems" would need to return AdGroup-object's for the posted JSON, but may need to return other types of objects for different types of report data.

```
class ReportModelExample {

    private $reportName;
    private $reportDate;
    private $reportItems;

    public function getReportName()
    {
        return $this->reportName;
    }

    public function setReportName($reportName): void
    {
        $this->reportName = $reportName;
    }

    public function getReportDate()
    {
        return $this->reportDate;
    }

    public function setReportDate($reportDate): void
    {
        $this->reportDate = $reportDate;
    }

    public function getReportItems()
    {
        return $this->reportItems;
    }

    public function setReportItems($reportItems): void
    {
        $this->reportItems = $reportItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some code there, what's the issue? Just set the object properties from the json data?

Comment: The issue is that I need and want to do this automatically. Using Java many years ago, I was using a library that with the help of annotations made this possible "in the background".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Additionally to my reply above, I would like to for example say that the "row" node should be de-serialized into an array of "AdGroup" instances. But different reports may need to de-serialize into "Keyword" instances, or "Campaign" instances.

Comment: Just create a class that takes this json as an argument in the constructor and parses it and iterates through the items and create new instances for them, storing them as an array in itself. For other reports, just extend that class and change what needs be changed. This should be pretty trivial.